# Sample size in simulation and stopping criteria

Tags: sample-size, simulation, monte-carlo, convergence, algorithms

I want to estimate the average of a random variable by simulation. Also, I want to estimate a proportion by simulation.

I know that there are formulas to calculate the minimum sample size so that the estimated value is closer than $e$ units to the real value, with (at least) $1-\alpha$ probability. They are the typical formulas used to calculate sample sizes in parametric inference. And I think they are OK.

However, I also remember, from my university days, using different stopping criteria when applying an iterative algorithm aimed at giving a final value as a result (e.g., root finding algorithms).

For instance, I remember setting a stopping condition based on the absolute or relative difference between the values returned by two consecutive iterations.

Example: Let $\bar{x}_{n}$ be the average of the $n$ first simulated values. Assuming that I want to estimate $\mu$, the population average, I would stop the simulation when $\left| \bar{x}_{n} - \bar{x}_{n-1}\right| < e$, for a given $e$ as small as needed.

Also, a stopping condition based on the relative difference could be used (i.e., stop when $\left| ( \bar{x}_{n} - \bar{x}_{n-1}) / \bar{x}_{n-1} \right| < \varepsilon$).

I vaguely remember that this approach presents some issues. For instance, despite the fact that the (absolute) difference between $\bar{x}_{n}$ and $\bar{x}_{n-1}$ can be small, if it is always positive or always negative for $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$, etc., this could mean that we are not yet close enough to the value we want to estimate, but that the estimation is 'moving' very slowly towards it. In other words, the fact that $\left| \bar{x}_{n} - \bar{x}_{n-1}\right| < e$ does not necessarily imply that $\left| \bar{x}_{n} - \mu \right| < e$ (obviously).

So, I am asking for some expert advice here. Are these stopping criteria I just mentioned too naïve? When can I use them? Is there any stopping criteria commonly used to decide when an algorithm has 'converged enough', based, for instance, on the *deceleration* of the successive approximations or estimations...?

---

EDIT

Just to make it clearer (I hope), I am interested in (Monte-Carlo) simulation (but not Markov-Chain simulation). I am also interested in knowing when to stop the simulation, so that a given accuracy (closeness to the true value) can be guaranteed. I thought that an approach similar to the stopping criteria for iterative algorithms could be applied here.

Comment: Can you clarify whether your question is how to determine whether an MCMC procedure has sufficiently converged? Determining convergence is different from assessing precision of estimates. And considerations for simulations can be quite different from considerations for iterative subroutines.

Comment: @AdamO I edited my question to answer your comment.

Comment: @Vicent The main issue with stopping based solely on the difference between consecutive estimates (either absolute or relative) is that it doesn't guarantee proximity to the true value ($\mu$, in the case of mean estimation). The observed difference under the threshold merely suggests that the estimates have stabilized relative to each other, not necessarily that they've converged to the true parameter.

Comment: @ADAM So, does this mean that the only valid approach is using the 'classical' formulas for sample size determination?